# Rails Asset Pipeline loads all files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have multiple files in my `app/assets/javscripts` folder, `application.js.erb`, `page.js.erb`, `sections.js.erb` & `scraped.js.erb`.

Rails loads them all in my layout with `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>` in `application.html.erb` layout. Which is called from the `PagesController`.

I do not want `scraped.js.erb` to be loaded at all & `sections.js.erb` I would like to only be loaded from the `SectionsController`.

From my understanding (after reading http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)  that's how the asset pipeline worked. That if called from the `PagesController` it would load `application.js.erb` & `page.js.erb` but obviously that's not the case.

Am I doing something wrong? Could someone explain to me how the asset pipeline works? And how I can only use select assets rather than all of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your manifest file, in assets/javascript you got the file application.js, it contains 
`//= require_tree .` which include during compilation all files of the directory tree.

If you want to exclude some files you can either require your files one by one: `// require my_file`, either create sub directories in your javascript directory and use 
`//= require_directory my_directory`

Read more http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html